# How to create grid image system in Bootstrap4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, grid

Here I have some pictures. I need picture 4 and 5 to be under picture 2 and 3. How can I do that with bootstrap4 and css3?

```
<main>
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-12">Anonymous</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!-- pic 1 -->
      <div class="col-6 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118375100_gettyimages-1304610824.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pic 2 -->
      <div class="col-3 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118809405_index.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pic 3 -->
      <div class="col-3 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118809064_tv067645357.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pic 4 -->
      <div class="col-3 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118803936_united-boom.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pic 5 -->
      <div class="col-3 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118803936_united-boom.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</main>
```

You can see it here. Picture 4 and 5 went in another line but I want to be under picture 2 and 3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to make them stack you should wrap each row with

```
<div class="row">
  Content
 </div>
```

Rememeber there are 12 columns in each row in bootstrap so if the sum of the columns exceeds 12 the content wont fit in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you'll want to make a row div that contains two col-6 divs. The first div will have the big picture on the left. The second div will contain another row div (that's right, it's a row within a row, like Inception!). Inside this row div, you'll have four col-6 divs for each picture.

[See it here on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7c9103s/)

```
    <main>
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <h1 class="col-12">Anonymous</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <!-- pic 1 -->
      <div class="col-6 card border-0">
         <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118375100_gettyimages-1304610824.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6 card border-0">
             <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118809405_index.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
             <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <!-- pic 3 -->
          <div class="col-6 card border-0">
             <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118809064_tv067645357.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
             <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <!-- pic 4 -->
          <div class="col-6 card border-0">
             <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118803936_united-boom.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
             <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
             </div>
          </div>
          <!-- pic 5 -->
          <div class="col-6 card border-0">
             <img id="img-anonymous" src="images/home picture/_118803936_united-boom.jpg" alt="Anonymous Hackers"/>
             <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <p>Anonymous Hackers:</p>
             </div>
          </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- pic 2 -->

   </div>
</main>
```